# Pick selective element from enum in C

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a algorithm to select random values from enum (written in C). This is enum belongs to Linux Kernel Driver. I use to access few IOCTL's provided by the driver. IOCTLS have an differentiation of FATAL and NON-FATAL values in the enum.

My application gets the input from the user to do "FATAL" or "NON-FATAL" operation accordingly. If it's FATAL I have to select randomly from enum (say for example 2,7,11 from enum) and same for NON-FATAL too.

The question is, there is no differentiation provided in the enum for FATAL and NON-FATAL (All the values maintained in same enum). So if the user inputs FATAL, I have to select 3 of FATAL from enum (I should not pick NON-FATAL) and the same for NON-FATAL too.

**Example,**

```
    enum kern_driver_enum {
                     POWER_OFF,
                     PANIC,
                     OOPS,
                     EXIT,
                     HALT,
                     SIGNALLED    
    };
```

Here I have POWER_OFF, PANIC, HALT as "FATAL" as it results in system restart. OOPS, EXIT and SIGNALLED as "NON-FATAL". So I should pick accordingly based on user input. This is just an example enum, the actual enum has around 30 values.

**Idea 1:** I am in thought of placing marker by re-arranging the elements and create a new enum in user space. And this needs conversion to make the kernel driver understands it's value.

**Idea 2:** Thought of creating two intermediate enum (one with FATAL and the other with NON-FATAL), but by adding dummy values in between to avoid the mismatch of values between kernel driver and user space.

Is there any way i can achieve this without maintaining local enums? May be something link maker.

Comment: One array for FATAL wherein 0th index could have value POWER_OFF and 1st, 2nd to PANIC, HALT, etc.
Similarly for second one, try OOPS, EXIT, SIGNALLED.
Choose any one index based on the FATAL, NON-FATAL and get the FATAL/NON-FATAL  value.

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/657341/